# Select Numerical Column Names

Tags: r

My dataframe looks like this:
[image]

I want to do the following: Select the highest and lowest value in 2020. I also want to add a column that shows the increase in cost from 2007 to 2020 and select the highest and lowest value there.

But when I try:

```
most_expensive <- university_cost[which.max("2020")]
```

or

```
most_expensive <- university_cost[which.max(2020)]
```

It just returns 50 rows of University names. I have no idea why.

Comment: Maybe: `university_cost[which.max(university_cost$"2020"),]` ?

Comment: returns the error that there is an unexpected numerical constant 
EDIT: Worked, just had to to `university_cost[which.max(university_cost$"2020"),`

Comment: dont post a picture of your data. Instead provide part of your data using `dput(head(mydata))`. Also. provide your desired output.